# Source permitting removing sticky adhesive backing from clothing on Shabbat?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing

Is there an issue with removing on Shabbos something sticky from fabric, for example, a feminine napkin from underwear, or a sticker from a sweater, if it tears off some fabric along with it? I heard someone say that Rabbi Ovadia Yosef permits such an action. Sources?

Comment: Why do you suspect this might be prohibited that you seek a source permitting it? Please edit to clarify

Answer (score 3):

It is true that Chacham Ovadia is lenient . This can be found in Yechaveh Daat 6:24 where be discusses adhesives. He brings many poskim who disagree and are machmir. See the teshuva inside . The underlying reason given is that since it wasnt put there to last it is mutar to separate, he does say that its preferable to remove before shabbos.

A relevant part from teshuva:

[image]

Comment: This is about separating the adhesive from its original production backing

Comment: Isnt that the OP question? A sticker from a sweater?

Comment: When the company produces it and sticks it to a paper backing, that's potentially tofer shel kayama and then korea could be an issue. Our case is where you stuck it to clothing within 24 hours intending to remove it soon. That's definitely not kayama so korea would be less of an issue